# How to customize an out of box form like issue tracking with optional section?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

[image]I am using "Issue Tracking App".Using Info path I am able to add new columns.
I have added a dropdown. Now based on the drop down I need to add optional section(I would format it hidden based on condition).The problem is there is no optional section in controls for an out-of-box list.

What can be the approach?

Comment: What you mean by optional section? Using conditional formatting you can show/hide sections

Comment: I am able to add section and able to hide rows .But as this is not an optional Section so what is happening is say I have 3 rows and based on my condition I need to show the 3rd row...As the first two rows are hidden it adds space  and  then Shows the 3rd Line.How Can I prevent this.I am attaching a screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the below setting can fix your issue

1. Make section height size auto. Right Click Section -> Properties -> Size -> Enter auto in height field -> Click Ok
2. Select the table row with possible hidden control -> Properties -> Row -> Set height as Auto.

Comment: Thank you @Amal .It works perfectly.Just rewriting the step so if someone else searches for same issue.1)I added a custom Table with just one row Set height as auto.2)Added a section inside it.3)Made the section Setting to Auto 4)Split the section into as many rows or column required.5)Enjoy adding the controls .Cheers!